# What's the difference between these 2 EF core queries? And is one better or faster than the other?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

Which one is better, faster or more efficient? Or does it not matter in this case?

```
account = await _dbContext.Accounts
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.AccountId == account.AccountId);
```

or

```
account = await _dbContext.Accounts
    .Where(p => p.AccountId == account.AccountId)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Or does it not matter in this case?

It does not matter. The performance difference if any will be negligible compared to the network call. And both queries will be translated to exactly the same SQL, something like the following:

```sql
SELECT a."AccountId", a. ....
FROM "Accounts" AS a
WHERE a."AccountId" ==  @_some_var_name_0
LIMIT 1
```

Some IDEs (Resahrper/Rider) actually will suggest to refactor second one into the first one.

Comment: When you say "refactor second one into the first one" do you mean use the second query?

Comment: @user1186050 no, it will suggest to use the first one - the one which is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in performance between the two approaches is likely to be minimal, and it may not matter significantly in most scenarios. Therefore, the choice between them can be based on readability, coding style, or personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it does not matter as @Guru Stron said. You can use this [tool](https://www.linqpad.net/) to help you visualize the SQL query that will result from your LINQ query.

However I do prefer the first option because It is easier to read when you have multiple conditions as so:

```
account = await _dbContext.Accounts
    .Where(p => p.AccountId == account.AccountId)
    .Where(p => p.AccountName == account.AccountName)
    .Where(p => p.AccountNumber == account.AccountNumber)
    .Where(p => p.AccountValue == account.AccountValue)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Why would you have multiple where clauses, why wouldn't you just say .where(something1 && something2 && something3) ?

Comment: Well you could do that, I just do not think it will look as clean when written out.